# HTML5 & CSS @media only screen and

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to put in @media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
but nothing happens.
I tried with something simple just to see if it's working, changing the background but nothing.

Do i need to write anything in HTML for this to work??

```
**{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  }
body{
    background-color:yellow;
}**
```

Even tried to but it in the bottom but nothing...

Comment: Move `body` above `@media` queries. Or put it into media query `min-width: 601px`.

Comment: media query is to be set last, else style will be overwritten.

Comment: If there is no content, `body` will have height zero and therefore seem invisible. ALso, as written in the comments above, swap the order since general rules will overwrite media queries when they follow after them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be seeing the changes due to the [specificity of the rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

That is, the way you have it written:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}

body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Both of these have the same specificity, meaning the *last* rule is what gets shown.

So, even if you are at a screen-size under `600px`, the `background-color: yellow` will be displayed.

Instead, you should define the non-media query rule *first*, followed by the media query rule *second*.

Try this:

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The media query must be written after the property you are going to make responsive.
In this case, first you write the code for body, after you write your media query.

**This is the example**

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answer on this thread you may need to include an important tag for the body in your media query. It will have to override the main body styles above.

So it should look as follows:

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue !important;
    }
}
```

The above means that your body will have a background-color of **yellow** on devices that have a width **LARGER** than 600px, and the body background-color will be **lightblue** on devices that have a width **SMALLER** than 600px.